# Google Trust Services certificate problem

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-cloud-speech, genesys

I'm doing some work with a customer to implement Google speech to text on the Genesys PureConnect platform to do voicemail transcription. A while back I installed this on the customers server and it was all working at that time. And now suddenly out of nowhere this is no longer working. What I am seeing is that we are getting an error when sending the REST request to the speech to text service.

The image below shows the error we are getting. The error is X509_¬V_¬ERR_¬SELF_¬SIGNED_¬CERT_¬IN_¬CHAIN and since this has appeared suddenly with no changes on my side I'm looking for ideas about anything that could have changed on the customers server that could have brought this on. This is on Windows server 2016. Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLGsb.png)

Comment: It seems that the security configuration of the server has been changed, thus you need to check your tls connection and check if any certificate is needed. but first what exactly the REST body (command) are you using ?

Comment: just enable TLS1.2 and disable TLS1.1